# Why would a C# method returning IEnumerable work when it returns a List but not when it yields?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, closures, yield

I have a method that generates a set of options for a floating drop-down menu. The method is of type `IEnumerable<FloatMenuOption>`.

When I return the values as a `List`, it works fine. But when I yield them one by one, every item runs the `useAct` lambda for the last one yielded, even though they all have correct labels.

Can anyone explain why this might happen? Why would returning a `List` instead of yielding the items one by one matter?

```
public override IEnumerable<FloatMenuOption> GetFloatMenuChoicesFor(Pawn myPawn)
{
    List<FloatMenuOption> options = new List<FloatMenuOption>();
    foreach ( Communicable commTarget in GetCommTargets() )
    {
        var localCommTarget = commTarget;

        System.Action useAct = () =>
        {
        Job openJob = new Job();
        openJob.commTarget = localCommTarget;
        myPawn.MindHumanoid.TakeOrderedJob(openJob);
        };

        options.Add( new FloatMenuOption(localCommTarget.GetLabel(), useAct) );
    }

    return options;

    //Simply commenting out the above line and uncommenting the two below causes the error
//  foreach (var opt in options)
//      yield return opt;
}
```

In either case, the options come out with correct labels (from `localCommTarget.GetLabel()`). However, if yielded, they all do the useAct lambda configured for the last item in the list, while if returned as a list they each do their own useAct lambda.

Why?

Comment: You have not told us what is the error

Comment: The problem is, "when I yield them one by one, every item runs the useAct lambda for the last one yielded".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

I believe if you change your for loop to:

```
foreach (var opt in options)
{
   var capturedOpt = opt;
   yield return capturedOpt;
}
```

you'll be golden.

Comment: I thought I was doing that, with the `localCommTarget` variable. Am I not?

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation, if your code yields the results instead of adding them to the list, only the last assignment to localCommTarget is used. The reason for this is the fact that the execution of the lambda expression is deferred to the actual access to the return. In other words, the order of execution is different for the different return strategies.

Comment: Since localCommTarget is declated inside the loop, each lambda should have a different copy of it inside its own scope. And anyay, why would adding them to a list make a difference? In either case, the lambda isn't run until localCommTarget has reached its final value.

And more importantly, how would I fix this if declaring localCommTarget inside the loop doesn't work?

Comment: The key point is not adding to the list, but conversion of the sequence to list, which triggers evaluation.